# How to turn a figure into a Tensor?TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a Figure into a Tensor

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am trying to implement a resnet18 model and train it to find protein's localization in cells image. I am working on a npy format of images, I have finally managed to put them into a dictionary along their labels. However I am now stuck in the sess.run step because it cannot be converted into tensor. is there any function that can help me with that?

I am new to Tensorflow so I don't know many solutions, I have only found function to turn numpy images into tensor using pytorch which isn't what i have.

this is the dictionary I have:

```
test_feed_dict ={ 
  plt.figure("self.dev_x") : test_batch_x,                  
  plt.figure("self.dev_y") : test_batch_y  
}
```

this is `self.dev_x`:

```
self.dev_x = np.load("/home/xxxxx/Desktop/project/data/0dev_x.npy")
```

This is where the error happens:

```
test_pred = self.sess.run(self.dev_pred, feed_dict = test_feed_dict )
```

Comment: I think I found a way to go around this problem (or more likely I went into this mess that wasn't correct),                                                                                          self.x_dev = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.img_size, self.img_size, self.c_dim], name = "dev_x")                                                                     test_feed_dict = {
                self.x_dev: test_batch_x,
                self.y_dev: test_batch_y
            }

Comment: this seems to be able to enter the dictionary, however I am getting another error at the moment so I can't check if it's still what I want in the dictionary.       ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.